# Number of subgroup of finite index

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups, profinite-groups

I study profinite group theory, and I need to show the following property:

Let $a_{n}(G)$ the number of subgroups of index $n$ in $G$ and $a_{n}(\hat{G})$ the number of open subgroups of index $n$ in $\hat{G}$;

Prove that $a_{n}(G)=a_{n}(\hat{G})$.

---

I think that it's enough to prove that start from the injection $j:G\longrightarrow \hat{G}$

(I suppose $G$ residually finite) we get a bijection between the set of subgroups $H$ of index $n$ in $G$ and the set of open subgroups $K$ of index $n$ in $\hat{G}$ given by $H \longrightarrow \bar{H}$ and $K \longrightarrow K\cap G$ and that the index in both case is preserved.

But how I can prove this?

Another little question: Does this implies that $\hat{G}/\bar{H} \cong G/H$, if $H,\bar{H}$ are normal subgroups ?

Comment: I don't have much time right now, but here are some quick hints to get you started. The second question is easy, just consider the map $\hat G\to G/H$, think about its kernel, and apply the isomorphism theorem. This then also shows that the maps above preserve the index. For your first question, you need to show the two maps are each others inverse. Hint: note that all the subgroups we care about are closed. I might write a more detailed answer tonight.

Comment: For the second question i used the map $G\rightarrow \hat{G}/\bar{H}$ and i found the isomorphism; but i don't understand why the canonical morphism $j:G\rightarrow \hat{G}$ send subgroups of $G$ into their closure in $\hat{G}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prove first that a map as above is actually a bijection:

in fact, let $K\leq_{o} \hat{G}$, then since $G$ is dense in $\hat{G}$ (in $G$ i take the profinite topology), $K\cap G$ is dense in $K$ so $\overline{K\cap G}=K$.

Conversely, let $H\leq G$, then $H\subset \bar{H}\cap G$ (obvious), but $\bar{H}=\underleftarrow{\lim}_{N\trianglelefteq G}HN/N$, where the limit is over all the normal subgroup of $G$ with finite index. Now if $(gN)_{N}\in \bar{H}\cap G$ (with the identification $G\hookrightarrow \hat{G},$ $g\rightarrow (gN)_{N}$) then $gN\in HN$, $\forall N$, so $g\in HN$; but if I take $H=H_{G}$ then $g\in HH_{G}=H$ and we get $\bar{H}\cap G\subset H$.

Now I prove that this bijection preserve the index:

Let $H\leq_{o} G$ and let $n=[\hat{G}:\bar{H}]$; Since $G$ is dense in $\hat{G}$, $G\bar{H}=\hat{G}$ and so $\hat{G}=\bigcup_{i=1,..,n} \bar{H}t_{i}$; but we can take the transversal $t_{1},...,t_{n}$ in $G$ and we have $G=\bigcup_{i=1,..,n} Ht_{i}$, so $[G:H]=n$.

Finally I prove that if $H\trianglelefteq G$ then $\bar{H}\trianglelefteq \hat{G}$ and we have: $G/H\cong \hat{G}/\bar{H}$:

in fact, if $H\trianglelefteq G$ then $HN/N\trianglelefteq G/N$, $\forall N$, so $\bar{H}=\underleftarrow{\lim}_{N\trianglelefteq G}HN/N\trianglelefteq \hat{G}$;

Now if $H\trianglelefteq G$ the natural morphism $G\rightarrow \hat{G}/\bar{H}$ have kernel $G\cap \bar{H}=H$; since $[G:H]=[\hat{G}:\bar{H}]$ we get the conclusion.